# Plot gets shifted when using secondary_y

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot temperature and precipitation from a weather station in the same plot with two y-axis. However, when I try this, one of the plots gets shifted for no reason it seems like. This is my code: (I have just tried for two precipitation measurements as of now, but you get the deal.)

```
ax = m_prec_ra.plot()
ax2 = m_prec_po.plot(kind='bar',secondary_y=True,ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('Times')
ax.set_ylabel('Left axes label')
ax2.set_ylabel('Right axes label')
```

This returns the following plot:

[My plot is to be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JZaB.png)

I saw someone asking the same question, but I can't seem to figure out how to manually shift one of my datasets.
Here is my data:

print(m_prec_ra,m_prec_po)

```
    Time
    1      0.593436
    2      0.532058
    3      0.676219
    4      1.780795
    5      4.956048
    6     11.909394
    7     17.820051
    8     14.225257
    9     10.261061
    10     2.628336
    11     0.240568
    12     0.431227
    Name: Precipitation (mm), dtype: float64 Time
    1      0.704339
    2      1.225169
    3      1.905223
    4      4.156270
    5     11.531221
    6     22.246230
    7     30.133800
    8     27.634639
    9     20.693056
    10     5.282412
    11     0.659365
    12     0.622562
    Name: Precipitation (mm), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Where is that other question and in how far does its answer not help here?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034863/matplotlib-secondary-y-cause-plot-to-shift-right The answer suggests that I shift the data, but I can't seem to make that happen

Comment: I see. That answer does not contain any code because the question did not provide any data to use for showing an examplary case; neither does this question.

Comment: I updated my question with the data now

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for this behaviour is found in [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49036550/4124317).

Here, the solution would be to shift the lines one to the front, i.e. plotting against an index which starts at 0, instead of 1.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : np.arange(1,11),
                   "B" : np.random.rand(10),
                   "C" : np.random.rand(10)})
df.set_index("A", inplace=True)


ax = df.plot(y='B', kind = 'bar', legend = False)
df2 = df.reset_index()
df2.plot(ax = ax, secondary_y = True, y = 'B', kind = 'line')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What version of pandas are you using for this plotting?

Using 0.23.4 running this code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data_1':[1,2,4,8,16,12,8,4,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data_2':[1,2,4,8,16,12,8,4,1]})

ax = df1.plot()
ax2 = df2.plot(kind='bar',secondary_y=True,ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('Times')
ax.set_ylabel('Left axes label')
ax2.set_ylabel('Right axes label')
```

I get:

[image: This graph]

If you want to add sample data we could look at that.